# How to copy file from remote server in shell script?

Tags: shell, ssh, scp

I need write script for copy remote server files to here automatically on server backend. something like below:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f   
  spawn /usr/local/bin/scpdata.sh
  set timeout 3000
  expect "root@172.100.100.143's password:"
  set timeout 3000
  send "xxxx"
  set timeout 3000
  send "exit\r"
  expect eof
```

scpdata.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash
  scp test@172.100.100.143:/tmp/11-03-15_03:00:01.tar.gz /tmp
```

But this not work, where is problem and how to do it? Please help

Comment: @user670809: what exactly gone wrong? the scp command?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you use public key authentication instead (generate public/private keypair with `ssh-keygen` on the client, add the public (`.ssh/id.pub` by default) key to `.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server—see the man page). Than you can either:

- Give the passphrase for the key in advance using `ssh-agent`, or
- use a key without passphrase.

In the later case I suggest you limit the key to a particular command. I am not sure how to set a command for scp, but

```
ssh test@172.100.100.143 'cat /tmp/11-03-15_03:00:01.tar.gz' > /tmp/11-03-15_03:00:01.tar.gz
```

is equivalent. You just write `command="`*the command*`"` in front of your key in `.ssh/authorized_keys`. Than the ssh server, when authorized with this key, will always run specified command no matter what was given on ssh command line. This limits the damage an attacker could do if they got access to your passphrase-less key.

If you need the name of file to get to vary, you will need to write a script on the server side, that will pull out the name of `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` (that's where the server-side script gets whatever was given on ssh command-line), check that it's one of the permitted files and cat it.

Comment: yes, it could be use ssh-keygen, but sometime can't change anything in server, that would still be problem.

Comment: @user670809: You only need to put the key in a file in home directory of the user you log in as, which is possible when you have simple ssh access. Any more advanced configurations where that would not be possible will probably be done by competent system administrator who knows (or at least will understand) why use and how to set up ssh public key authentication.

Answer (score 0):

1. You never "hit enter" when you send the password:  `send "xxxx\r"`
2. `set timeout 3000` does not actually pause -- it sets the timeout value to 3000 seconds (50 minutes). If you need to pause, `sleep 3`.

   - If your expect patterns are correct, you almost never need to explicitly sleep. Use `exp_internal 1` to debug your patterns.
3. Set up ssh keys and you don't need the expect script at all.